# Spring Boot Rest API @CrossOrigin Not working

Tags: rest, spring-boot

I know this question asked already but I have the same issue and did not find any solution

Spring Boot, I have Rest API and added a cross-origin annotation

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
```

But it still showing me an error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/API/findUser' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false}
```

I also tried

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE").allowedOrigins("*")
                        .allowedHeaders("*");
            }
        };
    }
```

But not working

Comment: refer https://howtodoinjava.com/spring5/webmvc/spring-mvc-cors-configuration/

Comment: @TheSprinter i tried this one also

Comment: Add here how you call your API. Is from Angular API, Postman, curl, other?

Comment: Did you get any solution to this? I run into a similar issue using @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")

Comment: @Rhycce yes I tried a different way

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if somebody found this question after some Googleing, this could potentially solve the issue.
If you are using Spring security. You should enable cors() there as well. Set your WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter like this:

```
       public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .cors() //<-- Enables CORS
                .and()
                    .antMatcher("/api/**")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .hasRole("admin")
                    .and()
                        .oauth2ResourceServer()
                        .jwt()
                        .jwtAuthenticationConverter(new CustomJwtAuthenticationConverter());
        }

    }
```